# Nutch 1.12 and elasticsearch 1.4.1 performance need

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I'm new in using Nutch and I want to crawl the whole seeds list that I have in entry.

First : I used the script : 
bin/crawl -i -D elastic.server.url=http://localhost:9200/index_name/ urls ksu_Crawldb/ 30

with : 2 CPU and 7.5 GB of memory

But after 2 days it just fetch 63500 document, and the CPU was only taken by 50% and not on the full time.

[image]

I want to know, how to fetch the max of documents in short time.

Second : what is the difference between topN, depth and rounds ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published some [benchmarks](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/the-battle-of-crawlers-apache-nutch-vs.html) on Nutch with an explanation of why the resources are not used at the maximum continuously. Basically, Apache Nutch is based on Hadoop and as such is batch-driven: the different operations are carried out in succession. See also [this Q&A](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/12/nioche-stormcrawler-web-crawler).

There are various ways in which the performance can be tuned but the key element is simply the diversity of hosts you are fetching from and the politeness settings.

> Second : what is the difference between topN, depth and rounds ?

topN is the number of URLs to select for fetching based on their score
depth is the number of outlinks from the seeds to get to a particular URL
rounds is the number of iterations of fetching/parse/update

depth and round are often the same but not necessarily

Comment: thanks for your response. I worked on the configuration of thread to deal with that.

Comment: I have also modified threads per queue and could achieve good response. @Julien Nioche: thanks for the info!